# Deploying repos with submodules using cloudflare pages

Tags: github, devops, git-submodules, cloudflare, jamstack

I'm deploying a project using cloudflare pages, and can see in the logs the initial git clone is working, however when the submodules are being pulled down the following error is thrown `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com`, the project are under the same organisation in github and .gitmodules is working as expected locally.

Any ideas on how to get submodules to working properly with cloudflare pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving this by updating the .gitmodules file and setting the src to include username@personalaccesstoken. You can also just use your personal access token.

Your file should look like this

```
[submodule "src/common"]
path = src/common
url = https://[Token]@github.com/[Org]/[Repo].git
```

Hopefully that helps anyone else who has a similar issue

Comment: Is it possible to add the [Token] as an environment variable defined on CloudFlare?